# What is meant by "one level deep"?

Tags: reactjs

Learning testing with React, and I came across this point from this article: https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-renderer.html

> When writing unit tests for React, shallow rendering can be helpful.
>   Shallow rendering lets you render a component “one level deep” and
>   assert facts about what its render method returns, without worrying
>   about the behavior of child components, which are not instantiated or
>   rendered. This does not require a DOM.

Can someone explain the concept behind "levels deep"? Does this have any relation to objects and how many levels deep they are?

Comment: It doesn't instantiate any child components of the one you render. You can Instantiate the parent component and check state, call methods etc without every child having to be rendered etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The depth of a component is the number of children and grand children it has:

```
const Level1Component = ()  => <Component /> // No children

const Level2Component = ({children}) => <Component>{children}</Component>
```

And if it's children have children, then it's `depth = 3` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

It means when testing a component with another component inside, you can just **focus on** the target component you want to test, and ignore the contents of it's child, grandchild, ... etc components.

For example, now I want to test a component called `<ParentComponent>`, which has a  `<ChildComponent />` inside :

```
<div>
   <h1>Hi</h1>
   <ChildComponent />
</div>
```

When testing with `<ParentComponent />`, it will not render the JSX part of `<ChildComponent />`, so the testing code can be more simple and pure:

```
import ShallowRenderer from 'react-test-renderer/shallow';

// in your test:
const renderer = new ShallowRenderer();
renderer.render(<ParentComponent />);
const result = renderer.getRenderOutput();

expect(result.type).toBe('div');
expect(result.props.children).toEqual([
   <h1>Hi</h1>,
  <ChildComponent /> // don't need to worry about what's inside
]);
```

( this example is similar to the React Doc )

Answer (score 0):

It is saying you can check the state of your parent-component with out rendering your child component state/data by just rendering the component. That make sense? One-level in this case the top level / shallow.

```html
<parent-component>
{parent-data}
  <child-component-1>{child-1-data}</child-component-1>
  <child-component-2>{child-2-data}</child-component-2>
</parent-component>
```